# ViewPager under the ToolBar not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a `ViewPager` under my `ToolBar` the thing is that the `ViewPager` is on the top of the layout eventhough if I put `layout_below="@+id/toolBar` that is the id from my `ToolBar`

This is my `activiy_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerMainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Note: on this layout I also added the `NavigationDrawer`**

This is the output:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

I've created this `style`

```
<style name="tabs" parent ="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">            
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/blue</item>
    </style>
```

And now I don't see the "shadow" because I've also deleted this line `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` but now I see the tabs `white` and I only see the selector line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
What I'm doing wrong?
```

The parent for both the items is `<FrameLayout`, and the latter stacks its children one on top of the other. You have to use a `<RelativeLayout`

Comment: RelativeLayout instead of FrameLayout?

Comment: Yap that's the trick thanks but I have like a "border" on the TabLayout is any default border?

Comment: I don't know... Try removing the theme.

Comment: The "shadow" I mean, is that possible to remove it?

Comment: add `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>` to your theme

Comment: "to your theme" Do you mean my `AppTheme`? If is this it doesn't change anything.

Comment: `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`?

Comment: what I meant was, can try adding `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>` to `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`

Comment: I don't have any style with that name

Comment: It's okay I solved it changing the parent for ` parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout"` thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Second thing you can also try is to have a linear-layout containing View Pagers directly inside a Main parent DrawerLayout. i've implemented it this way in my app.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
android:id="@+id/tab_layout_main_id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar" //app bar here.
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <com.faisal.soccerworld.tab_layout.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager // here's view pagers.!
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<fragment // this is navigation drawer.!
    android:id="@+id/fragmentNavDrawerID"
    android:name="com.faisal.soccerworld.tab_layout.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/DrawerWidth"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```